# Flutter: How to get children of items in Firestore database

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I have a Firestore database looks like this:

[image]

I'm trying to get the data to loop through each of the chats and add the data into the visibility Dashboard widget as the name of the chat and the last message sent so the app hopefully loos like this.

[image]

This is the code I have tried, I have looked around on how to do this but I could only find the solution in Java.

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: _firestore.collection('dashboard').snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot){
            if(!snapshot.hasData){

            }else{
              final dashboards = snapshot.data.documents;
              List<Dashboard> dashboardList = [];
              for (var dashboard in dashboards){

                final String nameOfChat = dashboard.data['chats']['nameOfChat'];
                final String lastMessageSent = dashboard.data['chats']['lastMessageSent'];

                final String username = dashboard.data['displayDashboardTo'];
                final String displayDashboardToUID = dashboard.data['uid'];

                dashboardCard = Dashboard(
                  nameOfChat: nameOfChat,
                  lastMessageSent: lastMessageSent,
                  displayDashboardTo: username,
                );

                dashboardList.add(dashboardCard);

              }

              return Visibility(
                visible: true, 
                child: Expanded(
                  child: ListView(
                    children: dashboardList,
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
          }
        ),
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since "chats" field is an array you'd have to loop thru it.

```
final dashboards = snapshot.data.documents;
List<Dashboard> dashboardList = [];
for (var dashboard in dashboards){
final Map data = dashboard.data;

var chats = data['chats'];

for(var chat in chats) {
  final String nameOfChat = chat['nameOfChat'];
  final String lastMessageSent = chat['lastMessageSent'];
  final String username = chat['displayDashboardTo'];
  final String displayDashboardToUID = chat['uid'];

  dashboardCard = Dashboard(
   nameOfChat: nameOfChat,
   lastMessageSent: lastMessageSent,
   displayDashboardTo: username,
 );

dashboardList.add(dashboardCard);

});

}
```